# add roads to map using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I add roads (or any transit infrastructure) to a map I've made in R? I think the generalization of the question would be how can I draw two layers on top of each other using `geom_polygon()` without the second overriding the first?

I'm specifically trying to do this using a map of Chicago's wards and a map of its bus routes. Both are available online here: https://data.cityofchicago.org/Facilities-Geographic-Boundaries/Boundaries-Wards-2015-/sp34-6z76 and here:https://data.cityofchicago.org/Transportation/CTA-Bus-Routes-Shapefile/d5bx-dr8z.

Code to plot each separately:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)

wards <- readOGR(dsn=path.expand("~/Desktop/Wards"), layer ="geo_export_d15e486d-2802-4700-afe7-9063b55d3e27")
buses <- readOGR(dsn=path.expand("~/Desktop/CTA_Routes"), layer ="CTA_Routes")

#Fortify Wards
wards.point <- fortify(wards, region = "ward")
colnames(wards.point)[6] <- "ward"
wardsmap.df <- join(wards.point, wards@data, by = "ward")

#Fortify Buses
buses.point <- fortify(buses, by = "OBJECTID")
colnames(buses.point)[5] <- "OBJECTID"
buses.df <- join(buses.point, buses@data, by = "OBJECTID")

#Simple Ward map
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = wardsmap.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               fill = NA, color = "black", size = 0.25) + theme_nothing(legend = TRUE)

#Simple buses map
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = buses.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               fill = NA, color = "black", size = 0.25) + theme_nothing(legend = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is with you data. They have different projection, so they looks like they are in different part of the globe.

```
wards@proj4string
CRS arguments: +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs

buses@proj4string
CRS arguments:
 +proj=tmerc +lat_0=36.66666666666666 +lon_0=-88.33333333333333 +k=0.9999749999999999 +x_0=300000
+y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Once we transform to a single projection all is fixed:

```
buses <- spTransform(buses, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
wards <- spTransform(wards, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```

After this, proceed as you did:

```
wards.point <- fortify(wards, region = "ward")
colnames(wards.point)[6] <- "ward"
wardsmap.df <- join(wards.point, wards@data, by = "ward")

#Fortify Buses
buses.point <- fortify(buses, by = "OBJECTID")
colnames(buses.point)[5] <- "OBJECTID"
buses.df <- join(buses.point, buses@data, by = "OBJECTID")

#Simple Ward map
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = wardsmap.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = 'black', color = "black", size = 0.25, alpha = .5) + 
  geom_path(data = buses.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), color = "red", size = 0.35)
```

Still looking a bit weird to me for what I know about Chicago, but again it's probably some projection woodoo I don't know about. And this should be enough to get you started

[image]

Comment: actually you can fix that projection issue by adding coord_cartesian() so if you make it the following it should be fine.

    ggplot() + coord_cartesian()+
  geom_polygon(data = wardsmap.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = 'black', color = "black", size = 0.25, alpha = .5) + 
  geom_path(data = buses.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), color = "red", size = 0.35)

Answer (score 1):

so here's the thing: it's going to over plot (or override as you say) because you're not assigning the variables to ggplot, so it writes to that each time. you need to assign one to ggplot (wards) and then over lay the other two data sets.

whats happening is each object here, ggplot and geom, is making a layer of the map. if nothing is assigned to ggplot is assumes the variables from the first geom. so that's why it looks like it's over riding, when in fact it's just writing layer one a second time. doing it in the fashioned out lined below draws two layers (the geom objects) on top of the base (the ward data).

This should work nicely.

```
ggplot(data = wardsmap.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +  
geom_polygon(data = wardsmap.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
           fill = NA, color = "black", size = 0.25) +
geom_polygon(data = buses.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
           fill = NA, color = "red", size = 0.25) + 
theme_nothing(legend = TRUE)
```

p.s. if you write all your layers to color=black it's going to look like they're not they're as well, but I assume that's just a typo, so I corrected here

also, improving from above since I see the coords weren't assigned:

```
ggplot(data = wardsmap.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +  
coord_cartesian()+
geom_polygon(data = wardsmap.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
           fill = NA, color = "black", size = 0.25) +
geom_polygon(data = buses.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
           fill = NA, color = "red", size = 0.25) + 
theme_nothing(legend = TRUE)
```